# Auto Populating fields in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

When a Story is linked to a Product Feature, I want all of its common fields to be copied over and they also need to be editable.

I've been looking into doing a Validator script that's sort of hybrid of the Condition script, but I haven't had any luck

```
string[] subtasks = subtasks(key);
string errorMsg = "All sub-tasks must be closed before a parent 
can be closed";
for(string subtask in subtasks) {
    if(%subtask%.status != "Closed") {
       return false, summary, errorMsg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you possible add a bit more detail to your question? The script you include does not seem to be related in any way to copying fields between issues. Also, are you only talking about custom fields, or all JIRA fields? Would you expect the 'Assignee' to be copied over? What about the created and modified dates?

Comment: Hi, yes. There are a few custom fields that I'd like to carry over, specifically the ones that are common to both our Story and Product Feature. These don't include the Assignee or create and modified dates. Just a due date. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to clone the 'Product Feature' issue and then change the issue type of the resulting clone to 'Story'.

That would work best if the fields on the 'Product Feature' issue type were a subset of the fields on a 'Story'.

This would only give you a one-off field copy though, it would not provide a dynamic update if the fields in the 'Product Feature' where modified.